# Subscription field must return Async Iterable. Received: undefined

Tags: node.js, graph, apollo, graphql-subscriptions, async-iterator

I use graphql nodejs with apollo-server.
When i try i got this error:
[image]

I already i returns pubsub.asyncIterator in resolver.
It returns error. Another project same setting works but there it is not working. I examine some stack issues here but i couldnt solve.

Server:
**App.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');


const { mainSchema } = require('./graphql/schemas/index');
const { rootResolver } = require('./graphql/resolvers/index');

const app = express();


const server = new ApolloServer({
typeDefs: mainSchema,
resolvers: rootResolver,
subscriptions: {
         path: `/graphql`,
         onConnect: (connectionParams, webSocket, context) => {
         console.log('Client connected');
},
onDisconnect: (webSocket, context) => {
         console.log('Client disconnected')
    },

  },
});

server.listen(3000, "192.168.1.106").then(({ url }) => {
console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

**Subscription Resolver**

```
    Subscription :{
    userNotifications : withFilter(
            ()=>pubSub.asyncIterator(NEW_NOTIFICATION_CREATE),
            (payload, variables)=>{
                console.log("payload=>", payload);
                console.log("variables=>", variables);
                return true
            }
        )}}
```

**PubSub.js**

```
  const { PubSub } = require('graphql-subscriptions')

  const pubSub =new PubSub()

  exports.pubSub = pubSub;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had must used subccribe keyword for subs define. Thanks me.
Subscription :{
userNotifications : withFilter(
subccribe: ()=>pubSub.asyncIterator(NEW_NOTIFICATION_CREATE),
(payload, variables)=>{
console.log("payload=>", payload);
console.log("variables=>", variables);
return true
}
)}}